# Simple WebGL Program, RotateTriangle(WebGL Programming Guide, chapter3), Fail to Work

Tags: webgl

I'm Sorry to paste a list of code, but it's very simple.I don't know why, not warnings no errors, it breaks down in silence.Here is the source code, it refer to a utils.js file, I promise there is no errors in the outer file. Because other programs base on that work pretty well.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            body { background: pink }
            canvas { background: orange }
        </style>
        <script src="utils.js"></script>
        <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
            attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
            uniform float uCosB, uSinB;

            void main() {
                gl_Position.x = aVertexPosition.x * uCosB - aVertexPosition.y * uSinB;
                gl_Position.y = aVertexPosition.x * uCosB + aVertexPosition.y * uSinB;
                gl_Position.z = aVertexPosition.z;
                gl_Position.w = 1.0;
            }
        </script>
        <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            var gl, canvas, shaderProgram;
            window.onload = function() {
                initCanvasAndGL("canvas");
                initProgram();
                initBuffer();

                gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

                var angle = 90 / 180 * Math.PI;
                var uSinB = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSinB");
                var uCosB = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uCosB");
                gl.uniform1f(uSinB, Math.sin(angle));
                gl.uniform1f(uCosB, Math.cos(angle));
                gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
            }

            function initBuffer() {
                var vertices = [0.0, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5];
                var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

                var aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(aVertexPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aVertexPosition);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400">
            Canvas Not Supported! :(
        </canvas>
    </body>
```

---

```
If you do suspect the utils.js, Here is the source code.
function initCanvasAndGL(canvasID) {
    canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
    var names = [
        "webgl", "experimental-webgl",
        "webkit-3d", "moz-webgl"
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
        try {
            gl = canvas.getContext(names[i]);
        } catch(e) {}

        if(gl) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!gl) {
        alert("WebGL is not available! :(");
    }
}

function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if(!shaderScript) {
        return null;
    }

    var str = "";
    var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
    while(k) {
        if(k.nodeType == 3) {
            str += k.textContent;
        }

        k = k.nextSibling;
    }

    var shader;
    if(shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else if(shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if(!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}

function initProgram() {
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if(!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders! :(");
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
}
```

You can put it together to run the program. But the result really makes me crazy.

Comment: 我知道了，
gl_Position.y = aVertexPosition.x * uCosB + aVertexPosition.y * uSinB;
应该改成：
gl_Position.y = aVertexPosition.x * uSinB + aVertexPosition.y * uCosB;

Answer (score 0):

yes as the other person commented - you need to change your gl_Position.y as

```
gl_Position.y = aVertexPosition.x * uSinB + aVertexPosition.y * uCosB;
```

then you get a red triangle displayed
enjoy

Comment: Thank You Very Much, It's Very Nice of you to watch the program!